# removeObjectForKey: doesn't call dealloc

Tags: objective-c, object, release, nsmutabledictionary

I was under the impression that removing an object from an NSMutableDictionary using removeObjectForKey:@"someKey" released the object being removed. However, the dealloc method of my objects is not being called when I do this. Do I have to explicitly release them? Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you sure something else isn't retaining your object as well as the dictionary?

Comment: Make sure nothing else is retaining object in question. Just in case send `autorelease` message when adding object to dictionary.

Comment: How do you allocate the objects that are added to the dictionary?

Comment: *Don't* do what @Elmantas suggested. Don't ever send an extra `release` or `autorelease` message 'just in case'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeObjectForKey` *will* call `release` -- assuming, of course, that your `@"someKey"` does actually match an object in the dictionary. However, calling `release` doesn't guarantee that the object will then get `dealloc`-ed. It depends what other ownership claims there are on it.

Since in this case the `dealloc` message isn't getting sent, we can conclude that something else has a continuing claim. This may or may not be the result of an error -- for example, if you have also passed the object to some system component, it might quite legitimately want to keep your object around longer than you do.

If that isn't the case, the most likely cause would be having done something along these lines:

```
[dictionary setObject:[[SomeClass alloc] init] forKey:@"someKey"];
```

That is, never relinquishing the initial ownership granted by `alloc`. Instead this ought to be done something like:

```
[dictionary setObject:[[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease] forKey:@"someKey];
```

Comment: I think you can read my mind! That's exactly what I've done (& your fix works) - I didn't see any need to release something which I was going to use & release later, so I don't think I quite understand. When I check when my object is being initialised, it only happens once, so why would I need to release it twice? Just when I thought I was getting the hang of memory management...

Comment: @Franklyn Initialisation only happens once, but multiple claims of ownership can be staked - the first one by `alloc`, then subsequent ones by `retain` - which may happen as a byproduct of other things, like adding to a dictionary. An object is only `dealloc`-ed when all ownership claims have been relinquished by matching calls to `release`, which again may happen as a byproduct of other things, notably `autorelease`, which basically means "call `release` in a little while". Since you called `alloc` you need to balance that with `release` or `autorelease`.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'm getting it now, no doubt a few more hundred hours making these things will drum it in... :)